# python Click Return the helper menu

Tags: python, python-click

I just started using python click module and I would like to have it automatically bring up the '--help' function anytime click throws an error.

test.py

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', default=Adam,
              help='The person to great.')
def test(name):
    print name
```

If I was to run the script from the command line as test.py --no_such_thing. Is there a way I could get the --help to come up instead of the normal
:Error no Option --no_such_thing

Answer (score 2):

In short, you need to modify the method `click.exceptions.UsageError.show`.
But, I have posted a more in-depth answer to this question, along with sample code, in the [answer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596070/python-click-custom-error-message/43922088#43922088).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Click 4.0+, you can disable automatic error handling for unknown options using [Context.ignore_unknown_options](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.Context.ignore_unknown_options) and [Context.allow_extra_args](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.Context.allow_extra_args):

```py
import click

@click.command(context_settings={
    'allow_extra_args': True,
    'ignore_unknown_options': True,
})
@click.pass_context
def hello(ctx):
    if ctx.args:
        print(hello.get_help(ctx))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()
```

In that case, your command will receive the remaining arguments in `ctx.args` list. The disadvantage is that you need to handle errors yourself or the program will fail silently.

More information can be found at the docs in the [Forwarding Unknown Options](http://click.pocoo.org/6/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options) section.